# Stacked Bar Chart: Changing the order of the stacked columns for just one of the bars

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Consider the "Stacked Sales Bar Chart" sample of achartengine (http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html). Now, imagine that in one of the months - say, November, 2007 sold more units than 2008. To represent this on the chart, we will have to change the order in which the "sections" are stacked. The section for 2008 will have to come first (dark blue) and the one for 2007 (light blue) will have to be stacked on top of it.

How do I go about getting this effect in achartengine? The way I see it, one cannot control the `Renderer` for each individual bar. The `Renderer` applies to a `Series` as a whole. Hence, if I provide the `Dataset` in the desired order, only the column for 2007 will be displayed (since the value for 2008, which is lower in value, is supplied first, and hence 2007 draws over it).

Comment: Bump! Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As you said it yourself one can't control rendering for each chart value (bar). It would  defeat the purpose of the stacked bar chart.

If the sales in 2008 were higher compared to the same month in 2007 the bar would show that - lower bar (2007) would be shorter and the higher (2008) would be longer.

I believe you are using the stacked bar chart wrong. If you wish to compare monthly sales per year you should use e.g. the line chart above it, i.e. the one showing "Average Temperature". You could easily see the difference in sales for each month, and if you want to have cumulative sales as reference you could add a third series as the sum of the first two series.

**UPDATE**

Or you could use the chart #6 ("Monthly sales in the last 2 years") as it exactly shows the difference in sales.

**UPDATE 2**

What you wish to have is each bar part sorted in descending order, i.e. a year with higher sales is below the one with lower sales. I doubt a simple change in [rendering](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html) would suffice.
To do that you would need to create a `SortedRangeStackedBarChart` that would sort series values before rendering them.

```
public class SortedRangeStackedBarChart
    extends org.achartengine.chart.RangeBarChart {

  void drawSeries(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually using this for sales data: the "Stacked Sales Bar Chart" was illustrative since it is quite close to my use case. If it is any help, my stacked bar chart represents a weekly schedule of user profiles (think phone silent, loud, night etc profiles). I display time on Y axis, day of week on X. Each bar is split into 5 sections: each denoting the time for which a profile is active. Since user can set the profiles in any order, I want to be able to re-order the sections. I see your point about implementing a `SortedRangeStackedBarChart`. I'll have to dig a bit before commenting.

Comment: Okay, I did some digging into the code and couldn't find any place where `RangeStackedBarChart` itself is used. Your idea could still be applied by extending `BarChart`, but the complexity seems prohibitive. The entire code assumes symmetry between the series and the colors.

Comment: Too bad. Have you tried other charting libraries (androidplot, chartdroid)?

Comment: I explored some of them (don't recollect exactly which ones). Most don't have the stacked bar option. Others don't fit my requirements (wrt licensing etc). It looks like I'll have to go down the `extends View` path.